# how to get an actively refreshing tasklist in command line (windows vista)

Tags: command-line, batch-file, windows-vista

How do i get the tasklist command to refresh over a period of time? Is there any way to do so? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. BTW i would prefer not having to download any outside command line tools. :) Thank you in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use anyone of the multiple methods previously posted here (search for "delay"). For example:

```
@ECHO OFF
:REFRESH

ECHO Put your Tasklist command here...

REM DELAY 20 seconds

REM GET ENDING SECOND
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-3 DELIMS=:." %%A IN ("%TIME%") DO SET /A H=%%A, M=1%%B%%100, S=1%%C%%100, ENDING=(H*60+M)*60+S+20

REM WAIT FOR SUCH A SECOND
:WAIT
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-3 DELIMS=:." %%A IN ("%TIME%") DO SET /A H=%%A, M=1%%B%%100, S=1%%C%%100, CURRENT=(H*60+M)*60+S
IF %CURRENT% LSS %ENDING% GOTO WAIT

GOTO REFRESH
```

Perhaps you may want to start this Batch file with low priority to not consume too much CPU time this way:

```
START "Tasklist Monitor" /LOW TheBatchFile
```